# create a nested resource automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

it seems probably a trivial question, but i cannot a straightforward solution in active record documentation.
I have one resource and a nested resource and has_one association between the two. Is there a way to tell active record to create automatically a new nested resource when a parent one is created? autosave parameter is not doing it.

Comment: why you dont wish to build a service for this, which will create both the records?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you means `after_create` callback:

```
class YourClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :build_child

  private

  def build_child
    Child.create(parent: self, other_params: ...)
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, is there no automatic parameter? it means i need to add a customer build method and a custom create method to the child model i suppose.

Comment: @joel, no need to do it. self in this case id paretn instance.